# Wobble functionality etc. allowed in iPhone App Store?

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

I'm currently designing an app for the iPhone and I'm deciding on some features that imitate several native iPhone UI components and elements.

In my app, the user has to arrange several items on screen. Basically, they are free floating (not in a grid). In order to be able to move them, the user has to hold a finger on one of the  items until all items start to "wobble". Just like on Springboard, when moving applications. Is it allowed to imitate this functionality?

Another function is the "split screen", as seen when adding an application to another application. The screen breaks open, showing a new group with the familiar textured background. In my app, some screens require a user decision by picking one out of four icons. I want to present this by using such a modal view over the main view, more or less like the "add to group" function of Springboard. Is this allowed?

I'm well aware that there are several programming questions related to my issue, but none of them covers whether apps are allowed if they include the functionality. Any help is greatly appreciated!

(On a side note, I read on HN today that Apple doesn't really answer questions to Support about app approval, therefore I ask here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the biggest problem you might have is the "free floating" functionality. There's a very big gray area as to what's accepted and, from my experience, you can't have an app with with seemingly floating windows like a desktop.

I can't see Apple having a problem with the Springboard functionality because the Facebook app has it. I would just try to make your own version and not try to reproduce the code.

Also, the Split Screen animation should be fine.

My 2 cents.

Comment: It's "free floating content" as in images that can be ordered on a screen. Still safe and sound?

Comment: As long as they're just images, yes, I'd say so.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the guidelines about such functions not being allowed. I have submitted to apple an app recently with a wobble function like you mention and the reviewer did not mention anything about this being not allowed (The app was rejected for another reason which has to do with content licensing).